# When logging with AOP, should we keep all logging in one class or divide amongst many?

Tags: logging, aspectj, aop

I'm trying to introduce AOP into a project in the form of logging. One thing I haven't found an answer for yet is how to handle very large aspects.

It seems intuitive that logging would be a single aspect. After all, it's one concern that's typically crosscutting into many classes (and thus why AOP is beneficial). But if we put all our logging into a single aspect, we also end up with a very large file, which I worry could be difficult to keep organized.

How do other projects handle logging with aspects and what are the pros and cons of their approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options. A few which come to my mind spontaneously are:

- Use a singleton aspect (this is the default) and keep a Map of loggers per class or per package. This is easy to implement, but has some runtime overhead because you need to determine the currently executing object's type dynamically.
- Use [`pertypewithin()`](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/pertypewithin.html) object instantiation and declare the logger as an instance variable of your aspect. This will create one logger per type.
- Use [ITD (inter-type declaration)](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-itds.html) in order to create an interface with a default implementation of a `getLogger()` method or so. Then make all target classes implement the interface, also via ITD. Last but not least, use the method in your advice.

All three solutions are fairly straightforward to implement. See what best meets your need. Maybe the second one is the cleanest, but it creates many aspect instances if you have many target classes. You can test it by yourself using a memory profiler such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). I know it is packaged into newer JDKs, but I recommend downloading a stand-alone version because it comes with more plugins, as far as I remember when using it last time. You can also use VisualVM to profile remotely, BTW.